# How to start dissertation abstract on the same line as the Abstract label

Tags: formatting, texstudio, thesis, abstract

The dissertation guidelines at my University requires me to have the abstract starting on the same line as the abstract label. This is the abstract definition given in the class file which I am using.

```
% ABSTRACT
% page ii (no number shown)
% should be double spaced. Heading is not indented. Written at top of page.
\begin{alwayssingle}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
{\parindent0pt
\addcontentsline{toc}{frontmatter}{\protect\numberline{}Abstract}
\vspace*{0in}
Name: \textsc{\@author}\\
Date of Degree: \textsc{\@degreeyear}\\
Title of Study: \textsc{\@title}\\
Major Field: \textsc{\field}\\
Abstract: {\makeatletter
\let\@currsize\normalsize
\makeatother
{\begin{singlespace}
\@abstract
\end{singlespace}}}
}`
```

This is the output which needs to be changed.
[image]

The abstract text should start on the same line as the `Abstract:`label (i.e.) there should be no newline after the label. I have tried commenting out some of the directives, but as I am not well versed with latex I am not able to get it to work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please do not forget to provide a full compilable [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass{}`.

Comment: Instead of `Abstract: ... \begin{singlespace} \@abstract \end{singlespace}`, use `\begin{singlespace} Abstract: \@abstract \end{singlespace}`. Does that provide what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand the code that you have shown. However, try using a simple `abstract`, ignoring what the class says.

```
 % abstractprob.tex  SE 624327

\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\noindent Abstract: \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract} The abstract text,
which may take several lines in the document but look like a
normal paragraph..

\mainmatter
\chapter{A main chapter}
The start of the main document's text.

\end{document}
```